# Как, кросплатформенно, определить директорию из которой запущен скрипт и задать путь к файлу на Python

Tags: python, файловая-система

Есть вот такой код на Python 3:

```
curFolder=os.path.dirname(__file__)
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(curFolder+r"\settings.ini")
```

Этот код нормально работает под Windows, но в Linux приходится менять слеш на обратный. Тоесть так:

```
curFolder=os.path.dirname(__file__)
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(curFolder+r"/settings.ini")
```

Как определять директорию в которой находится скрипт и подставлять название файла, так чтобы код был кроссплатформенным?
Спасибо.

Comment: `os.sep`, как я понимаю, хранит нужный разделитель

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from os import path

base_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
config_path = path.join(base_dir, 'settings.ini')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pathlib

config.read(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name('settings.ini')))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]